# SVN Commit failed, access forbidden

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

Recently I am facing problem of commit to SVN. The SVN server I am using is VisualSVN Server 2.5.9 and the client is TortoiseSVN 1.7.12.

At first, one user is having problem to commit files to SVN. But that user still can access to the repository and download the update. The second user on second PC is working properly. But today, the second user is having the same problem as the first user.

[image: Commit failed]

Why is this happen? How can the problem be solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the "Forbidden" error if your user account lacks access permissions to a repository or repository path; it makes sense to check authorization settings for your user account. Make sure your system administrator hasn't provided you with No Access permission to the repository path.

If you are sure that permissions are set correctly, then double-check the URL you use. URLs in Apache Subversion are **case-sensitive**.

Additionally, I advise you to read articles on authorization in Subversion and VisualSVN Server:

- [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html) about [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).
- [VisualSVN Team's article](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) about path-based authorization. It explains the principles of SVN authorization by comparing it with Windows Access Control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't get it. If it is the path problem, why they still can browse the folder and update the folder to their computer, but not commit? I have set the permission to everyone is read/write. I even tried to add their account with read/write permission to solve the problem, but it doesn't works. The thing is with the same configuration, it works before. And all the sudden, they cannot commit.

Comment: In our company's case. We used svn server on windows(visual svn). This allowed some users to checkout files even if the path has the wrong case. But when the user tries to commit.. it suddenly checks for wrong cases.

Comment: Be sure to check the actual authorization configuration file and don't rely on the VisualSVN Server Manager GUI.  The GUI only shows the paths that exist at the HEAD of the repository.  The GUI does not show the path authorizations on paths that have been deleted.
I could not create a tag or branch from the trunk. The server admin and I had already looked over all paths and authorization rules in the GUI, and I had read acess on everything.  It turns out I did not have access to some paths that had been deleted years ago.

Comment: @Otherside use `Get-SvnAccessRule` to view access rules for paths that don't exist in HEAD revision: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule

Answer (score 27):

If the problem lies client side, this could be one of the causes of the error.

On clients `TortoiseSVN` saves client credentials under

> Tortoise settings / saved data / authentication data.

I got the same error trying to commit my files, but my credentials were changed. Clearing this cache here will give you a popup on next commit attempt for re-entering your correct credentials.

Comment: This was my problem - I think it started after installing TortoiseGit

Comment: Same problem here. Sometimes a commit fails and I have to clear the auth data and re-enter my credentials to make it work again. It happens sporadically and I never found a permanent solution for this.

Comment: `rmdir /s /q "%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth"`

Answer (score 4):

The solution for me was to check the case sensitivity of the username. A lot of people are mentioning that the URL is case sensitive, but it seems the username is as well!

Answer (score 2):

As a new user to these two software packages, I experienced the exact same problem.  As was also discovered above, my solution was to use the same case letters as is in the Repository path.

Here's a tip that I find helpful:  In VisualSVN, you can right click on the path, then click "Copy URL to Clipboard" for pasting in Tortoise to be sure that the path is the identical case.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue in Mac where svn was picking mac login as user name and I was getting error as

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://repo:8443/svn/proj/trunk'
svn: E175013: Access to '/svn/proj/trunk' forbidden
```

I used the `--username` along with svn command to pass the correct username which helped me.
Alternatively, you can delete `~/.subversion/auth` file, after which svn will prompt you for username.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had this problem same as you.
My windows is server 2008 and my subversion info is :

TortoiseSVN 1.7.6, Build 22632 - 64 Bit , 2012/03/08 18:29:39
Subversion 1.7.4, 
apr 1.4.5
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.0g 18 Jan 2012
zlib 1.2.5

I used this way and I solved this problem.
I used [group] option. this option makes problem. 
I rewrite authz file contents.
I remove group option. and I set one by one.
I use well.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had this problem same as you.  You can get the "**Forbidden**" error if your commit includes different directories ; Like external items.

And ı solved in one step. Just commit external items in another case.

Additionally, I advise you to read articles on External Items in Subversion and VisualSVN Server:

VisualSVN Team's article about Daily Use Guide External Items. It explains the principles of External Items in SVN.

https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html

Answer (score 1):

My issue was my **SVN permissions.**

I had the same problem "Access to '/svn/[my path]/!svn/me' forbidden" when trying to commit files to a project I had been working on daily for several months.  After trying the steps above, I could not resolve the issue.  I also tried pulling the project down from scratch, logging in/out of SVN, etc.  Finally I contacted my company's IT department and there was a permissions issue that spontaneously emerged which changed my access from read/write to read-only access.  The IT department refreshed my permissions and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to commit csharp-files (*.cs). In the end the problem was that at some point i installed mod_mono, which made the *.cs-files inaccessible, through its configuration. So it may well be an apache-configuration issue, if only some sort of files are not accessible.

```
grep ".cs" /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*
...
mod_mono_auto.conf:AddType application/x-asp-net .cs
...
```