# Tortoise SVN commit Failed with message "POST of '/svn/xyz/!svn/me': 403 Forbidden"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

While trying to commint tortoise SVN gives error
"POST of '/svn/xyz/!svn/me': 403 Forbidden"

I am able to perform checkout.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026160/svn-access-to-svn-repo-name-svn-me-forbidden     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415743/svn-commit-failed-access-forbidden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVN Commit failed, access forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415743/svn-commit-failed-access-forbidden)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user account you use to authenticate to Subversion server has Read Only access permission only. Therefore, you can't commit but can do a checkout or update (i.e. read).