# VisualSVN Server: Can't add files; While changing files and adding new folders (including new files) is fine

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Installed **VisualSVN Server** (updated to newest version today) on one of our servers and everything worked fine.

Our IT department did an security check and found some weak ciphers, not secure port etc; I fixed these problems and the server got a new IP address and moved to live system.

- Since then I can't add new files to SVN anymore (x)
- Changing existing files is fine (/)
- Adding new folders is fine (/)
- If new folders include files, adding these files is fine (/)
- Just adding a new file to an existing folder will generate SVN error (x)

SVN error:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Changing file 'D:\Test\Test.txt' is forbidden by the server
Access to '/svn/Test/Test.txt' forbidden
```

Thanks for your help!

---

Things I tried so far:

- Created a new folder and used it as Repositories Root
- Created a new Repository with "All Subversion user have Read / Write access" inside
- Changed "Log On" user to a local Administrator (was "Network Service" user) for "VisualSVN Server" and "VisualSVN Background Job Service" Service.
- Checked access rights to Repository folder in file System, both (Network Service and new local Administrator) have Full control (read/write/modify/list/...)
- Found a workaround to add new files by adding them in a new folder and move them afterwards
- Created a new local user, gave him rights to all folder/files related to VisualSVN Server + added the user as LogOn for VisualSVN Server Services
- Uninstall VisualSVN Server, reboot, install VisualSVN Server, reboot

Comment: Check the server's log and see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415743/svn-commit-failed-access-forbidden/16416148#16416148

Comment: @bahrep Thanks for your help. There is no entry about this event in server's log. This happen to all user, not only to me (tested with 4 different users on their PCs). I already checked you link, VisualSVN is running as a Service, owned by the "Network Service" user. I wasn't able to locate this user and its privileges, but as he is able to create folder including files, it seems very illogical to me that the write permission is the problem here.

Comment: Check user permissions (access rules) that you set on the repository. Note that there has to be relevant events in VisualSVN Server Event log. Use the **Windows Event Viewer** to view the log under** Applications and Services**.

Comment: @bahrep as user permissions only available for read/write, it would kinda strange that write folder(incl. files) is possible but files not. Anyway, checked and removed all user specific rights, just gave Everybody read/write to everything. Same problem. About the **Windows Event Viewer**, I didn't see the any entry about the problem, it's not in VisualSVN Server part either in Server Activity part. But I can generate entry there by using wrong password for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason **httpd-custom.conf** wasn't empty...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD)
RewriteRule .*$ - [F,L]
```

...which caused the problem.
I have no clue what bastard put it in there - will track that later.
Anyway - working fine now!